# Dealloc called last after next class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am using the following code to switch from Helloworld Scene to levelmenu scene.

```
NSString *st=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"levelmenu"];
    CCTransitionFade *trans=[CCTransitionFade  transitionWithDuration:0 scene:[NSClassFromString(st) scene]];
    NSLog(@" before replaceScene");
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:trans];
    NSLog(@" after replaceScene");
```

I have put an NSlog in levelmenu init also, But I am getting the console output as.....

```
2011-03-29 10:16:24.307 testProject[6574:207] init levelmenu
2011-03-29 10:16:24.787 testProject[6574:207]  before replaceScene
2011-03-29 10:16:24.787 testProject[6574:207]  after replaceScene
2011-03-29 10:16:24.860 testProject[6574:207]  dealloc
```

Can we change the order of calling above sequence, i.e after calling dealloc of menu init of levelmenu should be called.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using dealloc/init for this.
You could try [CCNode onEnter]/[CCNode onExit](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#aa63ddd790457e6a2f218aacecaf31462), which are called when your scene enters / leaves the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Our game has 10 classes.
We have to move from one class to another after a time period.
The problem is when we move from one class to another the calling sequence is like this
1. function which will load the next class
2. init of second class.
3. dealloc of first class.

We are realeasing the arrays and unloading the sounds in dealloc of first class.
No memory leaks found in the analyser.

Comment: What we want is to call in this sequence.
1. first the function which loads the next class(this is ok).
2. dealloc of first class.
3. init of second class.

One more thing.
We are unloading the same sound in the dealloc of first class and preloading it in init of second class.Is that a problem.
Our game crashes after a while at irregular intervals.
We don't know what is the reason. We are thinking the above may be the reason.
We cannot find any memory leaks in any of the classes also.

Thanks.